# Data structures; converting list of tuples into dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of tuples like

```
data = [
    ('di', 'c1', 'avg11'),
    ('di', 'c2', 'stdev12'),
    ('eng', 'c1', 'stdev21'),
    ('eng', 'c2', 'stdev22')
]
```

How do I get the `'di'` and `'eng'` items into a dictionary which looks like this :

```
data1 = {'c1':'avg11','c2':'stdev12'}

data2 = {'c1':'stdev21','c2':'stdev22'}
```

using pandas or numpy or regular python?

Comment: Why the separate variable names? Why not just a top-level dictionary with `'di'` and `'eng'` keys?

Answer (score 2):

Using `Pandas` you could do

```
In [660]: data1, data2 = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index([0, 1]).unstack()[2].to_dict('r')

In [661]: data1
Out[661]: {'c1': 'avg11', 'c2': 'stdev12'}

In [662]: data2
Out[662]: {'c1': 'stdev21', 'c2': 'stdev22'}

In [663]: pd.DataFrame(data).set_index([0, 1]).unstack()[2].to_dict('r')
Out[663]: [{'c1': 'avg11', 'c2': 'stdev12'}, {'c1': 'stdev21', 'c2': 'stdev22'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

In pure Python, just build a top-level dictionary, using [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to materialise the nested dictionary if still missing:

```
result = {}
for outer, inner, value in data:
    result.setdefault(outer, {})[inner] = value
```

This is the simplest and more readable way of grouping your data.

Demo:

```
>>> data = [
...     ('di', 'c1', 'avg11'),
...     ('di', 'c2', 'stdev12'),
...     ('eng', 'c1', 'stdev21'),
...     ('eng', 'c2', 'stdev22')
... ]
>>> result = {}
>>> for outer, inner, value in data:
...     result.setdefault(outer, {})[inner] = value
...
>>> result
{'di': {'c1': 'avg11', 'c2': 'stdev12'}, 'eng': {'c1': 'stdev21', 'c2': 'stdev22'}}
```

If you **must** have `data1` and `data2` variables afterwards, just set those from the `'di'` and `'eng'` keys:

```
data1 = result['di']
data2 = result['eng']
```

but this is rather inflexible if you have more or fewer or different outer keys.

Comment: I am assuming this is an alternative for `defaultdict(dict)`. Does it have an advantage over it?

Comment: @ayhan: you get to control when a missing key produces a value; a `defaultdict(dict)` always uses the factory, while `dict.setdefault()` make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain python you could do

```
 def process_data(data):
    res = {}

    for itm in data:
        if itm[0] not in res:
            res[itm[0]] = {}
        res[itm[0]][itm[1]] = itm[2] 
    return res
```

Example of use:

```
>>> d = [
...     ('di', 'c1', 'avg11'),
...     ('di', 'c2', 'stdev12'),
...     ('eng', 'c1', 'stdev21'),
...     ('eng', 'c2', 'stdev22')
... ]
>>> print(process_data(d))
{'eng': {'c2': 'stdev22', 'c1': 'stdev21'}, 'di': {'c2': 'stdev12', 'c1': 'avg11'}}
```

Comment: Don't use `dict.get()` to test for the presence of a key; that's just wasted cycles as you return the value or `None`, then drop it again. Just use `itm[0] in res`.

Comment: Better to use `itm[0] not in res` (yes, my mistake)

Comment: What difference between `itm not in res` and `not itm in res`?

Comment: The first is a single operator `not in`, the other is two `not (itm in res)`. Currently CPython (the standard Python implementation) will optimise the second to be the first, but that's an implementation detail. See [What is more 'pythonic' for 'not'](//stackoverflow.com/q/17659303)

Answer (score 0):

With `itertools.groupby()` function:

```
import itertools

data = [
    ('di', 'c1', 'avg11'), ('di', 'c2', 'stdev12'),
    ('eng', 'c1', 'stdev21'), ('eng', 'c2', 'stdev22')
]
result = {k: {i[1]:i[2] for i in g}
           for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda x: x[0])}
print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'di': {'c1': 'avg11', 'c2': 'stdev12'}, 'eng': {'c1': 'stdev21', 'c2': 'stdev22'}}
```